# Modificar informação do lado cliente

Tags: java, activex, applet

Estou usando applet assinada para modificar algumas informações na maquina do cliente executar alguns comandos windows, isso é necessário devido a parte administrativa da aplicação.Porém a execução de applet esta obsoleta para alguns navegadores.

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que eu posso usar para substituir os applets, talvez Activex?

Obrigado!

Comment: O que exatamente tu precisa alterar no lado do cliente?

Comment: Se conseguiste resolver o problema seria excelente uma resposta explicando para outros com o mesmo problema poderem aprender também!